# Problems with Jquery and Tumblr

Tags: jquery, tumblr, paragraph

Im using a stupid Javascript combination for my tumblr based homepage to show a random positioned thumbnail on hover and get a bigger picture on click. I have a few problems:

1. tumblr automaticly puts text inside a paragraph, which creates a space behind Link 1 (which doesn't work very well with the ",").
2. when i have a video that i make bigger and play, it continues to play when the display collapses.
3. I havent found a solution for creating a wordwrap behind the text before the Links. I would like it to look like this:
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text, of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Link 1, Link 2

I also have to write the image link twice, but i can live with that.

Very grateful if somebody helps me.

ps. See it in action here: http://roingbaer.com

```
$(".front").each(function() {
 var right = Math.floor(Math.random()*800);
 var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);

 $(this).css({'margin-right': right});
 $(this).css({'margin-top': top});
});

hoverdiv = $("div.hover")

hoverdiv.on("hover", function() {
$(this).children(".front").show()
});
hoverdiv.on("mouseleave", function() {
$(this).children(".front").hide()
})
hoverdiv.on("click", function() {
$(this).children(".back").toggle()
$(this).children(".front").hide()
});​
```

CSS

```
p { margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline;
}

.back { 
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
text-align:right;
}

.front
{ 
display:none;
max-height:200px;
max-width:auto;
position:fixed;
z-index:-50;
top:0;
right:100px;
}

img{ 
max-width:inherit;
max-height:inherit;
right:0;
top:0;
}


.hover { 
cursor:pointer;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-style:italic;
display:inline;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
<div class="hover"><a href="http://example.com">text</a>
<div class="front"><img src="http://images.roingbaer.com/ludvig.png"/></div>
</div>
<p>, of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>

<div class="hover">Link 1
<div class="front"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lyz7fjMdnN1rp3eymo1_r2_500.jpg"/></div>
<div class="back"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lyz7fjMdnN1rp3eymo1_r2_500.jpg"/></div>
</div>
<p>,</p>
<div class="hover">Link 2
<div class="front"><iframe frameborder="0" height="233" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VMeXGE_a8Gg" width="400"></iframe></div>
<div class="back"><iframe frameborder="0" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VMeXGE_a8Gg" width="853"></iframe></div>
</div>
    </div>

    ​
```

Comment: I think you should break this out into 3 different questions and try to clean up the code so only relevant information is shown for each.  Also please explain what you have access to.  For example I see that text is "automatically" being placed inside a `<p>` tag but can you edit the HTML or are you just pasting what was generated?